# TOC in DITA - Count nodes in different documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

How is it possible to acces and count nodes in linked xml documents with the xsl:number function?

I´m trying to aim something like `<xsl:number level="multiple" format="1.1." count="someNode | document(@href)/someOtherNode">` but within the 'count' function it´s not possible to use the 'document()' function. Therefore there must be another way to access elements stored in other '.xml' - documents.

**EDIT**
For what I understood is that I have to create a **temporary copy of my whole node-structure** for 1st performance and 2nd readability (and 3rd of course - accessability).

My Idea: I want to store the whole nested node tree in a readable variable. Therefore I have to create a variable and copy all nodes plus their content into it.

This is my desired file structure:

1. **Root** Document .XML contains all language specific documents as ditamaps
   `<map>
   <navref mapref="de-DE/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   <navref mapref="en-US/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   <navref mapref="es-ES/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   </map>`
2. **Language specific manuals** (.ditamap) - multiple documents possible
   `<bookmap id="X000263" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <chapter href="A.2+X000264.ditamap"/>
   </bookmap>`
3. **Chapters** for each manual
   `<map id="X000264" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <topicref href="A.2+X000265.ditamap"/>
   </map>`
4. **Contents** (.dita) or **SUB-Chapters** (.ditamap)
   `<map id="X000265" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <topicref href="A.2+X000266.dita"/>
   <topicref href="A.2+X000269.dita"/>
   <topicref href="A.2+X000267.ditamap"/>
   </map>`

All these documents contain several nodes that I want to count and easily access (e.g. to prevent over-using the *document(@...)* function.

I started to create a temporary copy of all contents like so:

`<xsl:variable name="spine">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection('../../?select=*.xml;recursive=yes')">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>`

I´m aiming for a solution that just reads through all the .xml / .ditamap /.dita documents in their correct order and that gets me a 1:1 copy of all nodes and contents. Then I could easily read the stored variable node tree and would not have to manually traverse through all documents. And of course I could easily count then all nodes of a specific type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the DITA-OT for publishing? If yes, it might not be necessary to parse external documents because all information is gathering in a single file during preprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and yet another request on Stackoverflow, I got a working solution for my needs. The following describes the way I´m handling the situation right now:

1. Create a **composed document** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986773/create-composed-documents-with-xslt-href)) stored in a variable
2. Now I can apply the templates according to the variable like so

   `<xsl:apply-templates select="$myVar/document/*"/>`
3. With this I can easily access and count each node that exists in this *single source* document (as far as I understood it´s not possible to easily count nodes that are not composed in a single document)

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you can use the `doc` function in a pattern (`count` attribute is a pattern), but I doubt that would help you here.

But since you are omitting the `select` attribute, I assuming you are counting the context node. Unless the context node is in the document you are referring to, there is no way to count it, because the pattern must match the current node. If the context node is already in the document you are referring to, you can omit the `document` function in the pattern (leave the rest of the pattern in) and it will "just work".

If you are trying to count something that cannot be captured by a pattern, but requires a select expression, then you should manually create the numbers by using a combination of `count` expressions. Since I don't know your input document, I can't really give an example.

### Edit (after your edit)

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="//*">
>    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```

**Don't do this** (sorry for the bold ;). This has the effect that you create a copy of each descendant element. I.e.:

Input:

```
<root>
   <child>
      <deeper>
   </child>
</root>
```

will result in output like this (note how each descendant is copied again):

```
<root>
   <child>
      <deeper/>
   </child>
</root>
<child>
   <deeper/>
</child>
<deeper/>
```

In fact, something along those lines should suffice (I added the originating URI, may help with debugging):

```
<xsl:variable name="spine">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection('../../?select=*.xml;recursive=yes')">
        <doc original-href="{base-uri()}">
            <!-- assuming you do not need any comments in the root of the document -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>
        </doc>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you do not make a copy, I think you can still get what you want, but as said above, you may need to do some counting yourself.

Something I didn't mention: if you want to count nodes from several sources, and they differ in element name only, it may be enough to just write `count="someNode | someOtherNode"`. However, if `someOtherNode` is from a different document, then you must make sure that the current matching selection is in the correct order. By default, selecting multiple documents has implementation defined order.

In short, I think your suggested approach is good. I doubt it has performance benefits (because you are creating a copy of everything), but just time your solution to find out.

Comment: I got the following document structure in which I need to count several nodes: 1.) languages.xml - 2.) lang.ditamap - 3.) chapter.ditamap - 4.) content.dita

Comment: @garlicDoge: I don't see/get/understand the XML. It is probably best to provide (minimal) samples in your original question for better understand- and readability.

Comment: I think what I have to do is to create a **temporary copy of my whole structure** so that I can easily traverse through all the nodes and for e.g. count them. I understood that I can´t  reach nodes in my DITA structure if they are not contained in one single document.

Comment: @garlicDoge: thanks for your updated answer, it is much clearer now. I generally agree to your approach, but see my updated answer.

Comment: nice! thank you very much. how is it possible now to copy the node-structure for all nested documents in their correct order? With   `<xsl:for-each select="collection('../../?select=*.xml;recursive=yes')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>` i´d only get all the nodes from my **ROOT** document. So if i´d print out all the nodes with  `<xsl:for-each select="$spine/*">
            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>` i should get : map navref navref navref.

Comment: Sorry for the double-post but to be more specific: I have to gather the node-sets from inherit documents with different file-extentions (.xml / .dita /. ditamap ...). Is it possible to do this with a simple function such as _collection()_?

Comment: @garlicDoge: sounds to me like a new question (see [faq]), but in short, everything in XSLT deals with sequences, so if you cannot do it with one `collection` call (its flexibility depends on your `CollectionUriResolver`, or the default of the processor), you can add them together, separated by a comma, duplicates will automatically be removed. If you want to know of a way to do it cross-processor in one call in XSLT 3.0, ask a new question (not fit for just a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use DITA-OT (http://www.dita-ot.org/) to make the compound middle file from root document (map). DITA-OT's "preprocess" and "TopicMerge" processing will generate following structured merged middle file:

1. Expanded map structure portion composed of only topicref elements (in your case).
2. Topic body portion referenced from map portion.

Usually TOC is generated by the stylesheet from map structure portion by counting the topicref elements hierarchy.

From your example, I have noticed that the root map is composed of navref elements. The navref reference will not be resolved from its DITA definition. Using mapref element instead of navref will resolve the reference and the referenced contents will be included into the merged middle file.

This is the most convenient way to accomplish your requirement.