# Create Composed Documents with XSLT (@href)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, dita

How can I create a node-tree for all my referenced documents and store it into a variable with XSLT? (I´m using XSLT 2.0)

This is my file structure:

1. **Root** Document .XML contains all language specific documents as ditamaps
   `<map>
   <navref mapref="de-DE/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   <navref mapref="en-US/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   <navref mapref="es-ES/A.2+X000263.ditamap"/>
   </map>`
2. **Language specific manuals** (.ditamap) - multiple documents possible
   `<bookmap id="X000263" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <chapter href="A.2+X000264.ditamap"/>
   </bookmap>`
3. **Chapters** for each manual
   `<map id="X000264" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <topicref href="A.2+X000265.ditamap"/>
   </map>`
4. **Contents** (.dita) or **SUB-Chapters** (.ditamap)
   `<map id="X000265" xml:lang="de-DE">
   <topicref href="A.2+X000266.dita"/>
   <topicref href="A.2+X000269.dita"/>
   <topicref href="A.2+X000267.ditamap"/>
   </map>`

I´m aiming for a complete xml-tree (you could say a 'composed' document) with all files correctly nested into their reference giving parent nodes.

Is there an easy way to create a composed document with `<xsl:copy-of>` (maybe with mutliple 'select' options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write templates following the references e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy elements that don't need special treatment, then

```
<xsl:template match="navref[@mapref]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@mapref)/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter[@href] | topicref[@href]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@href)/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="nested-tree">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you want to write other templates then to process the variable it might make sense to use modes to separate processing steps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="composed-doc">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="compose"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="navref[@mapref]" mode="compose">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@mapref)/node()" mode="compose"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter[@href] | topicref[@href]" mode="compose">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@href)/node()" mode="compose"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If I want to do this XSLT transformation as an own process - I mean not including all the other stuff I do in my stylesheet(s); how can I do this with modes? I´d be very thankful if you could describe this in your answer.

Comment: @garlicDoge, if you simply want a stylesheet that follows all references and output the composed document then you don't need any modes, I have edited the answer and provide a sample stylesheet that uses the snippets suggested earlier.

Comment: I need the composed document stored in a variable. But with no modes set, some of the nodes that I put into the variable are already converted to e.g. `<fo:block` elements.

Comment: @garlicDoge, I have edited the answer to use a `mode="compose"` to store the composed document into a variable and to separate that processing step from other steps. If you don't need the first template, the identity transformation, for other processing steps then simply use `<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="compose">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="compose"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>` there as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is excactly what I needed. Also I got a bit into using different modes. Wish I could give +100 :)